# How can I automate Google account login using selenium?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Automate Google account login using selenium

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("path/to/chromedriver");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com");

IWebElement emailInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId"));
emailInput.SendKeys("your_email@gmail.com");
emailInput.SendKeys(Keys.Return);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement passwordInput = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("password")));
passwordInput.SendKeys("your_password");
passwordInput.SendKeys(Keys.Return);

driver.Quit();
```

Automate Google account login through selenium